# Generic SQL Error on create of contact in dynamics crm 2011

Tags: c#, sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I've unregistered all plugins and deactivated all workflows for the contact entity and also there is nothing at the on save event of the **contact** entity  in MS Dynamics CRM. Also, I've restarted all async services and even IIS. But still I am facing SQL Server Generic error. Here in the following is the log file of the error.

**Update: Error Logging Details**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Generic SQL error.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147204784</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>CallStack</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ExternalMessageDispatcher.ExecuteInternal(IInProcessOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IPlatformMessageDispatcherFactory dispatcherFactory, String messageName, String requestName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, ParameterCollection fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId, Guid transactionContextId, Int32 invocationSource, Nullable`1 requestId, Version endpointVersion)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, UserAuth userAuth, Guid targetUserId, Boolean traceRequest, OrganizationContext context, Boolean returnResponse)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>Generic SQL error.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2015-10-21T12:23:26.1555718Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

**Note:** this only happen to contact entity

Comment: There's not enough detail in this log. Can you turn on logging on the CRM server en get the details from the log files produced there?

Comment: I've only such information from the tracing service.

Comment: Looks like a custom plugin causing the error. If your deployment is on premise, you should be able to get a server log.

Comment: do you have a plugin running on Contact.Create event?  I agree with Henk - that appears to be the culprit.

Comment: Ignore previous comment, I re-read your question and it states that. Does this error window pop up when trying to create the contact (and block you from saving)?  If there are no plugins, javascript, or workflows - there is no custom code that is running on the contact create.  This would likely indicate an issue with your install (SQL server contact table got corrupted or on of the SQL procedures got modified or something like that).  Is this issue reproducible, or is it transient?  Please post plugin registration screenshot as well, in case you missed unregistering a plugin/step.

Comment: You need to investigate the issue further, try SQL traces and CRM error logs.

Comment: be sure that you are not submitting any strings that are longer than their corresponding fields allow (or similar way of breaking SQL data constraints) - this would cause a generic sql error, fyi.  It would also help to take a screenshot of the contact that you are trying to create and is failing

Comment: The problem is resolved using CRM Diagnose Tool along with Error reader.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally caused by the Duplicate Detection system.

To disable this setting open you CRM then go to Settings -> System -> Data Management -> Duplicate Detection Settings

https://prashantmayur.wordpress.com/2018/03/25/dynamics-365-crm-duplicate-detection-error-generic-sql-error-microsoft-crm-duplicatedetection-microsoft-crm-hasduplicatesplugin/